# Unexpected output zero

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm new to C++ and currently practicing on a Singly Linked List. Somehow the output of the code below is always zero. I think the problem is the nextPoint Method but however I try to change the reference/dereference, it doesn't work.

Where is the problem? Thank you in advance.

```
// Singly Linked List

#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

class Point {

        public:
        double x, y;
        Point* next;

        // constructor
        Point (double x, double y) {
                this->x = x;
                this->y = y;
                this->next = NULL;
        }

        void nextPoint(Point nexti) {
                this->next = &nexti;
        }

        double dist(Point &a, Point &b) {
                double dx = a.x - b.x;
                double dy = a.y - b.y;
                return sqrt(dx*dx - dy*dy);
        }

        double length() {
                Point *iter = this;
                double len = 0.0;
                while (iter->next != NULL) {
                        len += dist(*iter, *iter->next);
                        iter = iter->next;
                }
                return len;
        }

};

int main() {

        Point p1(1,1);
        Point p2(2,2);
        Point p3(5,5);
        p1.nextPoint(p2);
        p2.nextPoint(p3);

        std::cout << p1.length() << std::endl;

        return 1;

}
```

Comment: You're using `Point &` for `a` and `b`, but `Point` for `nexti`. Do you understand what each of the constructs means? What made you select the parameter types the way you did?

Comment: BTW, if you're learning C++, a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1782465) might come in handy.

Comment: `Point &` is the objects address so pass-by-reference and just `Point` is pass-by-value, right? Because I didn't want to copy the whole Point object I used `&` in `dist()`. Because the `nextPoint()` wasn't working I changed them up a bit.

Comment: More or less (`Point&` is a reference to a `Point`, not really an address). That was a leading question, though. Why are you passing into the `nextPoint` function by value?

Comment: In the beginning I also used & but because it hasn't worked I changed it.

Comment: Randomly adding/removing pointers/references/dereferences/whatever by trial and error is not a way to learn programming, I'm afraid (or at least to be any good at it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please turn on more compiler warnings and you'll probably get a warning that in `nextPoint` you are storing the address of a temporary variable (`nexti`) permanently (in `this->next`).

You must either pass the address of or a reference to the point to add.

```
void nextPoint(Point *nexti) {
    this->next = nexti;
}

p1.nextPoint(&p2);
p2.nextPoint(&p3);
```

or

```
void nextPoint(Point &nexti) {
    this->next = &nexti;
}

p1.nextPoint(p2);
p2.nextPoint(p3);
```

Side note: please replace `NULL` with `nullptr`.

Comment: I agree with Werner's answer, I would like to add something to your implementation A better implementation would be to name this class LinkedList and create a struct called Node for storing variables (x,y) and a Node* (a pointer pointing to the next element) Check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/) implementation of LinkedList

Comment: For me, both of your solutions still give the result 0. 

To compile I use `g++ file.cpp -o file`. Should I add the flag `-Wall` or should I even change compiler?

Comment: No, don't try to blame the compiler for this... It's almost never the compiler. And yes, you should turn on warnings; IMO, set `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` and never look back.

Comment: @underscore_d Okay, thank you. Because of my choice of points the result was always 0. Furthermore, my euclidean formula was wrong....

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with your code:

1. `nextPoint` takes its parameter by value, which means you're storing the address of that by-value parameter which becomes invalid as soon as the execution of `nextPoint` ends. Change it to accept `Point &nexti`.
2. Your distance computation function is wrong. You should be adding the squares, not subtracting them: `return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);`

---

Unrelated to your question, but there are several ways in which you could improve your code:

- Use the mem-initialiser list in the constructor to *initialise* members instead of *assigning* to them. This is a good habit to get into, as it will come useful once you start dealing with things where initialisation and assignment are substantially different (references, classes, ...).

  ```
  Point (double x, double y) : x(x), y(y), next(nullptr)
  {}
  ```
- Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`, since the latter is not type-safe.
- `length` should be marked `const`, because it does not modify the object on which it's called. Note that `iter` has likewise been changed to `const Point *`:

  ```
  double length() const {
          const Point *iter = this;
          double len = 0.0;
          while (iter->next != NULL) {
                  len += dist(*iter, *iter->next);
                  iter = iter->next;
          }
          return len;
  }
  ```
- `dist` does not use `this` at all, and so it could (and should) be made a `static` member function. Also, it should take its parameters by `const &`, because it doesn't modify them:

  ```
  static double dist(const Point &a, const Point &b) {
          double dx = a.x - b.x;
          double dy = a.y - b.y;
          return sqrt(dx*dx - dy*dy);
  }
  ```

Comment: Another reason the init-list is preferable, even if initialisation and assignment achieve the same end result, is that assigning to a member in the body means its default constructor is executed first, which is totally redundant as you then assign and replace what the default constructor did. This can cause non-trivial overhead for custom types. Using the init-list wherever possible is good practice because it avoids various kinds of pitfall and leads to more consistent/maintainable code even where no such pitfalls (currently) exist.

Comment: @underscore_d I actually consider (not) invoking the default constructor as "substantially different."

Comment: @Angew Thank you for your detailed answer. I see that using `nullptr` is necessary because `NULL` is not type-safe. However, what benefits does it bring to use `const`?

Comment: @rugkei Too big a question to handle in a comment; any decent C++ book will cover this, and even uncle Google should tell you something. One potential starting point is [the C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness). Just one point to mention: temporaries can bind to `const T &`, but not to `T &`.